# Why is process ID of running Windows services zero (QueryServiceStatusEx)?

Tags: c, winapi, service, pid

I need to determine the process ID of a Windows service (I'm using C). Seeing as I have access to the SC_HANDLE of the service, `QueryServiceStatusEx` is exactly the function I need. However, when accessing the dwProcessId field in the `SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS` structure returned by `QueryServiceStatusEx`, it contains 0.
Here is my code:

```
unsigned int get_svc_pid (SC_HANDLE svc) {

    unsigned int pid = 0;
    BYTE *svc_info = NULL;
    DWORD buf_size = 0;
    DWORD bytes_needed = 0;
    //determine svc_info size
    QueryServiceStatusEx(svc, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, svc_info, buf_size, &bytes_needed);
    svc_info = malloc(bytes_needed);
    buf_size = bytes_needed;
    //get pid
    if(QueryServiceStatusEx(svc, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, svc_info, buf_size, &bytes_needed) != 0){
        pid = (*(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS *)svc_info).dwProcessId;
    }else{
        fprintf(msglog, "ERR: QueryServiceStatusEx failed\nGLE: %u\n", (unsigned int) GetLastError());
    }
    free(svc_info);
    return pid;
}
```

Also: I've used `EnumServiceStatusEx` to enumerate all running services and output their names and PIDs contained in the `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS` structures. The majority of the PIDs were 0. Only a few PIDs in the structures matched those listed in ProcessHacker/TaskManager.

I'm at a loss as to why the dwProcessId fields contain 0, when clearly that can't be the valid PID. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because those services are not running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`QueryServiceStatusEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684941.aspx) documentation:

> The process identifier returned in the `SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS` structure is valid provided that the state of the service is one of `SERVICE_RUNNING`, `SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING`, `SERVICE_PAUSED`, or `SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING`. If the service is in a `SERVICE_START_PENDING` or `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` state, however, the process identifier may not be valid, and if the service is in the `SERVICE_STOPPED` state, it is never valid.

Just because you can obtain an `SC_SERVICE` handle to a service does not guarantee that the service is actually running.  `QueryServiceStatus/Ex()` tells you if the service is running or not in the `dwCurrentState` field.

You are also not doing any error handling on the first `QueryServiceStatusEx()` call.

Try something more like this:

```
unsigned int get_svc_pid (SC_HANDLE svc)
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    BYTE *buf = NULL;
    DWORD buf_size = 0;
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS *svc_info = NULL;

    //determine svc_info size
    QueryServiceStatusEx(svc, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, NULL, 0, &buf_size);
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        fprintf(msglog, "ERR: QueryServiceStatusEx failed\nGLE: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    buf = malloc(buf_size);
    if (!buf)
    {
        fprintf(msglog, "ERR: malloc failed\nsize requested: %u\n", buf_size);
        return 0;
    }

    //get pid
    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(svc, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, buf, buf_size, &buf_size))
    {
        fprintf(msglog, "ERR: QueryServiceStatusEx failed\nGLE: %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        svc_info = (SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS*) buf;
        switch (svc_info->dwCurrentState)
        {
            case SERVICE_RUNNING:
            case SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING:
            case SERVICE_PAUSED:
            case SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING:
                pid = svc_info->dwProcessId;
                break;
        }
    }

    free(buf);
    return pid;
}
```